# Why does $\Bbb Z[{1+\sqrt{-19}\over 2}]$ contain $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Why does $\Bbb Z[{1+\sqrt{-19}\over 2}]$ contain $1$? What multiples of ${1+\sqrt{-19}\over 2}$ form 1?

Edit:
Why does a subring of $\Bbb Z$ that contains ${1+\sqrt{-19}\over 2}$ have to contain 1?

Answer (score 5):

$1$ is in $\mathbb Z$, so
$$ 1 = 1 + 0\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2 $$

More generally $R[\alpha]$ is by definition the smallest ring that contains both $R$ and $\alpha$. Therefore every element of $R$ is in $R[\alpha]$ no matter what $\alpha$ is.

Comment: And if we take the “smallest sub ring that contains that complex number” definition?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt: That definition works only if a "subring" (of $\mathbb C$, presumably) is _defined to_ contain $1$.

Comment: Yes, smallest sub ring of $\Bbb Z$ that contains the complex number. So The ring $\Bbb Z $ contains 1

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt: Doesn't make a difference. A ring, by definition, has to contain $1$.

Comment: A ring has to contains 1? $2\Bbb Z$ is not a ring?

Comment: I don’t think it’s true that every ring has to contains a multiplicative neutral element

Comment: @Stanislas whether a ring has to contain 1 may depend on the book, but it usually does. Also, your phrasing is a bit off: no subring of **Z** contains a nonreal number.

Comment: If $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ meant "smallest subring containing $\alpha$", and "subring" were not defined to include $1$, then it would be a very odd choice of notation, since the resulting structure doesn't necessarily have any connection to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt: in some books, the notation is explicit: a "ring" has all the properties of a ring which includes a multiplicative unit; a "rng" has all the same properties except the multiplicative unit.

Answer (score 3):

There's a confusion here. The notation $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2\right]$ does *not* mean the multiples of $\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2$. It's the set of all numbers $P\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2\right)$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial with interger coefficients.

Now, consider the polynomial $P(x)=1$.

Comment: And what if you take the smallest subring of $\Bbb Z$ that contains ${1+\sqrt{-19}\over 2}$ definition?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt There is no subring of $\Bbb{Z}$ that contains $\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}$.

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt, what you meant was the smallest subring of $\Bbb C$ containing your irrational quantity. In this case, by “subring”, we understand a structure containing $1$.